# Does every new user have a unique default display pic?

Tags: discussion, design, gravatar

Do you just generate random patterns and give them to users, which is somehow non repeating? Also, where can I find more about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is called a [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/), which by default is generated by hashing your e-mail address. To change it you go to your account page (by clicking on your own username), click on "edit", and there is a link available for you to change your picture.

Theoretically, as a hash, the Gravatar is *not unique*. But the probability of actual collision is really, really low.

Comment: No, I didnt make it clear, then. My qyestion was, is this a non-repeating pattern? Is it unique for all users (have no interest in changing it or anything)

Comment: @yayu: Willie explained this in his answer, I will leave the proof of that as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: I see. By what process can someone automatically generate so many unique pictures, with low possibility of duplication?

Comment: @Willie One needs to distinguish between mathematical collision vs. end-result visual collision - which depends on many non-mathematical factors (screen resolution, visual acuity, etc). E.g. on screens that are smaller or lower resolution (e.g. phones) there's a higher probability of visual collision.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon

Comment: As suggested in Jeff's comment, the automatically-generated Gravatars are actually a specific subfeature of Gravatars called "Identicons."

Answer (score 8):

Googling Gravatar Algorithm from Willie's answer gave me the hint. Here are some other quesstions:

[what is the algorithm used to generate those little gravatar identicon images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392280/what-is-the-algorithm-used-to-generate-those-little-gravatar-identicon-images)

[How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)